# "App references non-public selectors in Payload" with Ionic 6 Cordova app and Xcode 14.0

Tags: cordova, app-store-connect, ionic6, xcode14

I am seeing the same without the name of the non-public selector in Payload...Not sure what this means and I am stuck .... Can someone help? [image: Error when uploading the app to App Store]

Ionic Info:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.1 (/Users/iosdev/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.2.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.2.2
@angular/cli                  : 14.2.2
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
Cordova Platforms : ios 6.2.0
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 20 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.4
native-run  : 1.7.0

System:

ios-deploy : 1.11.4
ios-sim    : 8.0.2
NodeJS     : v16.17.0 (/Users/iosdev/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/node)
npm        : 8.15.0
OS         : macOS Monterey
Xcode      : Xcode 14.0 Build version 14A309

Answer (score 0):

Firebase messaging plugin "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated" was causing this issue. Deleting it and building the app again worked. Need to find an alternative to this plugin to implement in the app.